# Question disappeared from search list after voting to close

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, question-lists

I voted to close the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859406/printing-all-string-stored-in-trie-tree. Having done so, I refreshed the page listing all [unanswered Java questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java) and the question had disappeared.

I double-checked and it was still tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) and still open, with no answers at all. Why did it vanish off the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be documented clearly anywhere, but the Unanswered lists for individual tags filter out questions with negative score. (The main Unanswered page does not, however, which suggests this may be a bug)

Correction: the main Unanswered page appears to filter them, but have the list in a cache so a recently-downvoted answer may still appear in the list for a while)

Comment: Good observation! This is definitely not well documented. Either this has changed recently, or I've been incredibly unobservant for the past two years.